# How shoud I deal with an update mixed with "thanks"?

Tags: discussion

I recently provided an accepted answer to [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/787962/recover-partition-table-for-exfat-partition).

The OP [edited the question roughly two hours later](https://askubuntu.com/revisions/787962/4) to include additional clarifications on the steps he did after following my suggestions. It mixed these details with a "thank you" comment.

It seems to me that I should simply rollback the edit. Am I correct? Or should I ask the OP to include that information inside my answer or even as a comment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest converting the new part of the question to an answer, mentioning that it is an answer by the OP. And also mark it as a community wiki.

It is too long for a comment, but looks like a valid answer to me.

**Update:** I converted to an answer.

Comment: Ok, thanks. Actually I don't think it's an answer, or let me say it differently, I don't see what it adds to my answer apart the fact that it explicitly states to press "Advanced Scan" in TestDisk. The rest looks pretty much like mine. :-)